# vuejs how to run emit on every array change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got an array in child component like this:

```
arrayChild: 
    [
    {name: 'name1', text: 'text1', buttons: 'false', active: "true"}, 
    {name: 'name2', text: 'text2', buttons: 'false', active: "false"}, 
    ...
    ]
```

I want to emit the arrayChild on every change in the `name`, `text` and `active` (not `buttons` change!)

How can I do it?

I created basic function to emit this on button click:

```
<btn @click="emitParent()">emit my Array</btn>

  emitUp() {
    this.$emit('offerArray', this.arrayChild)
  }
```

But it emit only on button click. I need to emit this automatically on any change within name, text and active. How can I do it? Should I use some kind of computed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Vue.js offers [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)! So you can "watch" a property and when a change is made you can do stuff.See below:

```
export default {
  data() {
     return {
       propertyName: 'valueOfProperty'
     }
  },
  watch: {
    propertyName(theNewChangedValue) {
      //do stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

> Also consider a deep watcher,that is useful when working with array of objects

```
    propertyName: {
        handler: function(newValue) {
            //do stuff when array of object changes
        },
        deep: true
    }
```

Comment: oh, this could be very helpful!

Comment: Yes,but you said that you want to emit when the array changes.So you are using array of objects so use the deep watcher and where it saying do stuff put your emit.

Comment: Sure, I'll try this way